# asp.net application running in production is crashing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net application written using a combination of technologies such as Asp.net MVC,WebAPI,SignalR etc and it is crashing almost everyday randmoly. I get this message logged by IIS in the event logs

> Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 6.0.3790.3959, stamp 45d691cc,
>   faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.4062

- There are no erros in my application log(log4net)
- There are no other logs in the application and system logs
- I cannot install any tools or profiler in the production server as it requires many levels of approvals and privileges.

I understand that we can use some kind of CLR profiler to get the crash analyzed but even that requires approval and we had a situation where the profiler was causing real slowness to our application as the application is very chatty(Hence signalR) .So I am looking for a solution with minimal impact on runtime but would like to figure out the root cause of the crash.

Comment: Do other things get correctly logged by log4net? Do you have a global error handler to log uncaught/unhandled exceptions?

Comment: also look into elmah error logging for future error https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSWdmlp5qaY very easy to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WER](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaun/2013/11/12/steps-to-catch-a-simple-crash-dump-of-a-crashing-process/) helped me troubleshoot this issue.Enabled crash dump using WER

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
�
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\w3wp.exe]
"DumpFolder"=hex(2):63,00,3a,00,5c,00,64,00,75,00,6d,00,70,00,73,00,00,00
"DumpCount"=dword:00000002
"DumpType"=dword:00000002
```

And this created an hdmp file and I was to get this analyzed using [debugdiag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577477.aspx) and windbg  to find out the issue. There was a stackoverflow exception happening and caused the application to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using dedicated application pool for your app ? 
if not, you can try to add new application pool and configure it for your application.